# как вызвать диалоговое окно с вводом текста в C#

Tags: c#

По определенному событию(например по тапу на кнопку) нужно чтобы вылазило диалоговое окно в котором можно ввести текст который потом присваивается переменной. Как вызвать просто диалоговое окно с надписью ясно понятно. А вот чтобы туда можно было вводить текст не хватает мозгов(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В VB.NET имеется функция `InputBox`, которая показывает пользователю простенький диалог для ввода текста.

К этой функции можно получить доступ и в C#-проекте. Для этого нужно добавить в проект ссылку на сборку `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (меню **Project** -> **Add reference...** и отметить в открывшемся окне строку с `Microsoft.VisualBasic`) и затем вызвать метод [`Interaction.InputBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Введите текст:");
}
```